# infopath: where is manifest.xsf located?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2013, infopath

i have a similar error  like this : 
[InfoPath - Cannot open, Form definition (.xsf) contains errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363037/infopath-cannot-open-form-definition-xsf-contains-errors)

but have no idea where to find the manifest.xsf file.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in InfoPath --> press file, and choose Publish, then choose Export Source Files. The XSN is then extracted to the seperated files in a map, one of that file is the manifest.xsf.

When you did your changes, press right button on the xsf file and choose Design, youre are then back in InfoPath.